# HTML/CSS svg auto height & width

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to make the svg automatically scale to the size of the circle inside it? Something like  or something. At the moment I give the svg a size, and the circle a size. Which causes them to not match (and I don't want to manually try and match both every time).

See how the blue background is bigger than the circle. I know I can just change the height and width, but it would be nice to have this change according to the circle size. I only want to change one element, not match both.

```css
.divOrangeCircles {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: aqua;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="divOrangeCircles"><svg height="200" width="200"><circle cx="90" cy="90" r="90" fill="#F48043"/></svg></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry but dint understand your requirement

Comment: Just make the blue background fit exactly around the circle. By changing the svg elements (not the div)

Comment: Check my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is the [`viewBox='x y width height'`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox) attribute, which will define the view-box of your SVG drawings.

SVG units are (generally) relative to their parent's box, by setting the viewBox attribute, you define how much of this units your SVG should display.

```css
.divOrangeCircles {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: aqua;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
svg {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="divOrangeCircles">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 180 180" height="200" width="200">
  <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="90" fill="#F48043"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes! Perfect! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Give your `cx`, `cy` and `r` should be in percentages in order to modify according to the Parent svg size.

[Sample Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/16px6v8a/2/)

For controlling sizes from css u can make svg height and width as 100% and give size from css.

```
<div class="divOrangeCircles"><svg height="100%" width="100%"><circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" fill="#F48043"/></svg></div>
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/16px6v8a/5/)

- Help :)

Comment: Still not working man XD. The idea is, if I change the circle size to something else, then the svg should also change with the circle size...so if I change the circle to 20%, then the svg should also scale down (automatically)

Comment: Add width: 180px and height 180px for wrapper to adjust the rectangle with the circle. https://jsfiddle.net/16px6v8a/7/

Comment: Svg is parent element and circle is the child element. Child will inherit actual dimensions from parent elements.

Comment: Thanks for your effort but I don't understand how this works. Where do I change the circle size? And then the svg should adjust automatically

Answer (score 0):

If you want to svg scale according to parent div then use this code. Don't be add manually dimensions in percentage.

```
.divOrangeCircles svg{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This is the same answer as @Help's answer, right? Check the comment I left at his answer.

Comment: @Frank not same he adding % in svg code. I am handling with the CSS :)

Comment: I tried this, doesn't seem to work though. It just makes the svg the same size as the parent div